# Creating records from selectedRows in Lightning:Datatable and seeing [no error object available] script error

Tags: lightning-datatable

hope your keeping safe and sound. Stuck on a new learning and hopefully someone can steer me in the right direction. Thanks as always!

Long story short, I am trying to select some PricebookEntry records from a Ltng:Datatable and then create quote lines from them using the selectedRows attribute. Not seeing any errors on the console log but when I select a row I get a 'sorry to interrupt' popup.

Apex Class: Passing the selectedRows in a list plus the Quote ID as a string. (I think...)

```
        @AuraEnabled
    public static List<QuoteLineItem> createQuoteLines(PricebookEntry[] selectedRows,string QuoteID) {

     List<QuoteLineItem> qli = new List<QuoteLineItem>();
    for(PricebookEntry selpbs: [SELECT Id, UnitPrice, Product2Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Id IN:selectedRows]){
        QuoteLineItem NQL = new QuoteLineItem();
        NQL.Product2Id       = selpbs.Product2Id;
        NQL.PricebookEntryId = selpbs.Id;
        NQL.UnitPrice        = selpbs.UnitPrice;
        NQL.Quantity         = 1;
        NQL.QuoteId          = QuoteId;

        qli.add(NQL);
    }
    insert qli;
    return qli;


}
```

Component

```
<aura:attribute name="valueFromParent" type="string" required="false" description="" access="public"/>
<lightning:datatable 
        data="{!v.pelist}" 
        columns="{! v.PEcolumns }" 
        hideCheckboxColumn="false"
        keyField="Id" 
        selectedRows="{! v.selectedRows }"
        onrowselection="{!c.doql}"
                             />
```

Controller

```
doql : function(cmp) {
    var action = cmp.get('c.createQuoteLines');
    action.setParams({
        selectedRows : cmp.get("v.selectedRows"),
        QuoteId : cmp.get("v.valueFromParent"),

    });
    action.setCallback(this, $A.getCallback(function (response) {
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            cmp.set('v.qllist', response.getReturnValue());
        } else if (state === "ERROR") {
            var errors = response.getError();
            console.error(errors);
        }
    }));
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
},
```

Comment: What does the "sorry to interrupt" message say?

Comment: Hey, thanks for all the help so far BTW.

Comment: This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. First, would you give us some details? (We're reporting this as error ID: -1886919150)

Comment: [NoErrorObjectAvailable] Script error.
a()@https://static.lightning.force.com/eu17/auraFW/javascript/5EkiQjrG-amda9Z1-HgsDQ/aura_prod.js:936:169
{anonymous}()@https://static.lightning.force.com/eu17/auraFW/javascript/5EkiQjrG-amda9Z1-HgsDQ/aura_prod.js:936:362
cn.dispatchEvent()@https://static.lightning.force.com/eu17/auraFW/javascript/5EkiQjrG-amda9Z1-HgsDQ/aura_prod.js:4:25839
cn.fireSelectedRowsChange()@https://get-clever-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/datatable.js:2:55660
cn.U()@hed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning/datatable.js:2:12515

Comment: Should add too that I have this table wrapped in an Aura: If which shows and hides it based on a Lightning:Input text search term being entered. I am not doing a search merely selecting but it could be causing a conflict. The table gets replaced by another if a search is performed.

Comment: I have ruled out the aura:if table show/hide as causing any issues. stumped!